# Entity Framework Database First with Database Schemas

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to interact with an existing legacy database.  This database uses a design structure I have never seen before and I am trying to figure out how to interface with it using Entity Framework.  The database design is made up about six TABLE_SCHEMAs adn they are all linked with foriegn keys.  The application creates a new set of tables every few hours and uses a datetime stamp for the TABLE_NAMEs.  I will give and example below

- TABLE_SCHEMA: TopLevel

  - Id int
  - Level1Id int
  - Level2Id int
- TABLE_SCHEMA: Level1

  - Level1Id int
  - data1 nvarcharv
  - data2 nvarchar
- TABLE_SCHEMA: Level2

  - Level2Id int
  - data3 nvarcharv
  - data4 nvarchar
- Tables:

  - TopLevel.20171121_0816
  - Level1.20171121_0816
  - Level2.20171121_0816
  - TopLevel.20171121_1127
  - Level1.20171121_1127
  - Level2.20171121_1127

There is a table for all of the TABLE_SCHEMAs for each of the datatime stamps TABLE_NAMEs.  I want to be able to run queries across an entire TABLE_SCHEMA and then access the linked tables.  Has anyone seen this design structure before and how to you interact with it?

Comment: You won't be able to use the model building features of EF for continuously created tables. At that point just build your own SQL statement.

Comment: Only if this application can be rewritten to add *data* instead of *tables* there's a good chance that EF will be useful. On the face of it there could be only one table having a date and a level field added. The current database structure is a disaster when it comes to querying, let alone any form of reporting or BI.

Comment: I completely agree, unfortunately this is something that inherited and I am just trying to build an app that can read data from the database that the main application is generating.

Comment: You could use EF for the static part of the model and Dapper for the mutable part.